# Unable to Load CSV to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Error Message: "Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position"

I'm having issues loading data from a CSV in Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery and creating an associated table. I'm starting with Cloud Storage, adding my raw CSV file there. Then, moving to BigQuery, Create Dataset > Create Table using the CSV in the Cloud Storage.

My CSV format is;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCbSX.png)

The Parameters in my BigQuery table are;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcDU3.png)

I can't get the data to load while in this format and this setup. the original dataset goes to 10k+ plus rows, however I've reduced the scope to troubleshoot the format error.

Any response or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the specific error?  I have tried to recreate given your parameters but it works fine.

Comment: Did you try with the CLI?

Comment: Here is the error output that I get - "Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 9, but line starting at position:273 contains only 1 columns."

Comment: You likely have an issue with the definition of the CSV.  Either an additional pipe, missing double quote, embedded comma.  But the definition you have in your sample and the parameters in your example work together.